# Can I have two sitemaps on one WordPress site

Tags: seo, sitemap

I have a WordPress site geared towards our Chinese audience in China and around the world. I'm using the Yoast SEO plugin for general SEO, but I’ve been trying to do some things that are helpful for SEO in China. I installed a plugin that generates a Baidu sitemap and also enabled the Yoast SEO XML sitemap; after doing so the Yoast plugin reported a conflict with the Baidu sitemap.

Can you tell me if there’s any concerns I should have with this conflict? I’d like to have a sitemap that will work in China (Baidu sitemap) *and* another one that will work in the rest of the world (Yoast SEO xml sitemap).

I wrote to the Yoast SEO forum, but am not getting any responses so I'm reaching out here.

Comment: You need to checkout robots.txt documentation and see if you can have two different sitemaps for different search engines. you might also be able to configure such a thing with the search engine provider (google web master tools and the like)

Comment: What does it say conflicts?   Are they trying to use the same file name, or is it just that they have many of the same URLs in them?

Comment: The Yoast plugin reports: "The following file is blocking your XML sitemaps from working properly. Either delete it or disable Yoast SEO XML sitemaps. The Baidu sitemap is called "sitemap_baidu.xml" so I don't think there should be a file name conflict.